# Custom row component in VList virtual-table-ant-design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I use virtual-table-ant-design and I need to stylize my rows(background, color etc). My styles come from props + I use less, so I can't use css styles, only inline
When I use VList, onRow prop doesn't work, and I decided to write custom component TableRow, but my table renders only one row (datasource contains 50 lines) and styles work!
So, why my table renders only one row? If I use table without VList - everything is okay.

This is my table

```
      <Table
        scroll={{ x: 'max-content', y: virtualHeight }}
        showSorterTooltip={false}
        className={classNames('resizable-table', { extraClasses: [className] })}
        onRow={(record, index) => {
          return {
            onClick: () => {
              setSelectedRow(index)
              onClickRow && onClickRow({ index: index, value: record })
            },
            index: index,
            record: record
          }
        }}
        rowClassName={(record, index) => {
          return index === selectedRow ? 'activeRow' : ''
        }}
        {...tableProps}
        rowKey="key"
      />
    </>
```

and this is my components vatiable

```
 const components = useMemo(() => {
    const initialHeader = initialComponents?.header ?? {}
    const { body: { cell, row, ...rest }, table } = VList({ height: virtualHeight })
    return {
      header: { ...initialHeader, cell: ResizableHeader },
      table,
      body: {
        ...rest,
        row: TableRow,
        cell: TableCell,
      }
    }
  }, [initialComponents, virtualHeight])
```

my TableRow component

```
export const TableRow = (props: any) => {
    const style = {
        backgroundColor: props.index % 2 === 0 ? props.even.color : props.odd.color
    }
    return <tr {...props} style={style} />
}
```

I can use only virtual-table-ant-design lib, it's project requirement

I tried to read docs, but it is so bad...
If i don't use components - table renders okay, but i need difficult styles for cells and rows

I try to move styles into datasource, but in this case my props doesnt reach custom component
I try to delete onRow props from table (maybe something conflict), but i have the same result + i can't put props to my TableRow)))

Comment: In TableRow component, return this: `return <tr {...props} style={{...props.style, ...style}} />;`